# Post daily on Facebook with the Facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook

first i want to ask if its possible to post on a facebook page all day a post with the PHP SDK.

Here is my version (it works but the token expires after some hours)

```
<?php

    define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR','../sdks/facebook/');

    require_once("../sdks/facebook/autoload.php");

    $access_token ="EAACEdEose0cBAGVFnr3vE8U6FYXxsJbRadxZB4ynIWaG5aFzDo0bx6vdIWysh4sPvnOPu3CHZCfLSM9MYLRRlvdeyJazIXgP0h3fqbbNc3oxg24b4I7rZChUS1FNHqm1HsWbym4IjsaoVw4fAqRlYfPsw2iX4nFZB7KDeAu1BglrRg2qGug8";
    $app_secret ="c19ca5fc56bc0ddce32c75a3cb53059f";
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '17852532523721',
  'app_secret' => $app_secret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
  ]);
    $linkData = [
  'link' => 'http://www.url.com/',
  'message' => "Test"
  ];

    try {

        $response = $fb->post("/42935243503912968/feed",$linkData, $access_token);

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

?>
```

It's possibole to get the actual acces_token of my users. Maybe someone now a solution.

Big thanks

Comment: i hope you don´t want to autopost on a user profile? that id is probably from a user profile, not a page. in order to post to a page, you can use an extended page token. read the docs about tokens.

Comment: @luschn the id is changed ;) but thnx for the tip :)